# Kernel dies after starting exploration strategy using NNI package

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, automl

I am following the nni package tutorial of Neural Architecture Search (NAS) https://nni.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/hello_nas.html.

But my kernel dies every time once I run

```
exp.run(port=8079)
```

The output is:

```
[2023-11-10 10:09:08] Creating experiment, Experiment ID: ...
[2023-11-10 10:09:08] Starting web server...
[2023-11-10 10:09:09] Setting up...
[2023-11-10 10:09:09] Web portal URLs: ...
[2023-11-10 10:09:09] Successfully update searchSpace.
[2023-11-10 10:09:09] Checkpoint saved to .../checkpoint.
[2023-11-10 10:09:09] Experiment initialized successfully. Starting exploration strategy...
```

Then, the kernel died.

I am using Apple M1 Max if this is relevant. Any suggestions?